# Approximating areas between functions using the Trapezoidal Rule

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I understand how to apply the trapezoidal rule to approximate the area under a curve.

But I'm not sure how to apply it when approximating areas between two functions.

- Do you use the formula like how you normally would, except apply it to the **first function - the second function**?

Or is there a completely different approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you use the formula like how you normally would, except apply it to the **first function - the second function**?

Yes. That's exactly what you would do.

Alternatively, you could use the trapezoidal rule to find the area under each function separately, then subtract the two results. Apart from possible rounding errors, that approach will give exactly the same result as your suggested approach, just as it does for exact integrations.

Answer (score 1):

If $g(x)$ is the top curve and $f(x)$ is the bottom curve, then the area between them is:

$$\int_a^b g(x)-f(x) \ \mathrm{d}x$$
$$= \int_a^b g(x) \ \mathrm{d}x - \int_a^b f(x) \ \mathrm{d}x $$

and then you can apply the trapezoidal rule on $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ separately to calculate the result.

Comment: Oh okay, so to find the total approximated area, you would apply trapezoidal rule to both functions then minus the result of g(x) with the result of f(x)?

Comment: Yes, that's what you would do.

Comment: makes sense. Appreciate the help!

Comment: I have approximated the area of the individual functions, however both return a negative value. Would you know what this means, or if its even possible?

Comment: How about you edit your question to include the full context?